# What does the union in angle brackets, $\langle \bigcup_{i\in I} N_{i}\rangle $, mean?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $\mathbf{G}$ be a group.
>   Let $\{N_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a collection of normal subgroups of $\mathbf{G}$, then prove that $\langle \bigcup_{i\in I} N_{i}\rangle $ is normal subgroup of $\mathbf{G}$

We proved this in class, but I didn't understand actually what does $\langle \bigcup_{i\in I} N_{i}\rangle$ mean with this notation. Does that mean that this collection of normal subgroups of  $\mathbf{G}$ is the generating group of $\mathbf{G}$?

Comment: Adayah's answer below is correct.  If you have $\langle x \rangle$ then you should read this as "the group generated by $x$" or if you prefer "the subgroup generated by $x$".  So $\langle x \rangle = \{x^n : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$
And $\langle \{x,y\} \rangle = \{x^{n_1}y^{n_2} : n_1,n_2\in \mathbb{Z}\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$\langle \bigcup_{i \in I} N_i \rangle$" is the subgroup of $\mathbf{G}$ generated by the union of all the elements of the $N_i$.  You are not proving that this object is $\mathbf{G}$, you are proving that it is a normal subgroup:
$$\left\langle \bigcup_{i \in I} N_i \right\rangle \trianglelefteq \mathbf{G}$$

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ is a group and $A \subseteq G$ is a subset, then $\left< A \right>$ denotes the least subgroup in $G$ containing $A$. Equivalently,

$$\left< A \right> = \left\{ a_1^{\varepsilon_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n^{\varepsilon_n} : a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A, \ \varepsilon_1, \ldots, \varepsilon_n \in \{ -1, 1 \} \right\}.$$

Now just let $\displaystyle A := \bigcup_{i \in I} N_i$.

Comment: Would one require each $\varepsilon_i\in\{-1,0,1\}$? If not, how can you construct the identity in <A>$?

Comment: @kam Letting $n=0$ we get the product of $0$ elements which by convention is the identity.